# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused / SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, laravel-8, docker-compose

estoy hace una semana teniendo un problema con mi api local.
Windows decidió unilateralmente actualizarse y cuando quise abrir ubuntu-22.04 en wsl me empezó a tirar un error así que decidí reinstalarlo.
Volví a configurar el entorno como es habitual:

En powershell:

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
wsl --set-default Ubuntu-22.04
```

En Ubuntu:

```
sudo -s
apt update
apt upgrade

apt install php8.1-cli
php -v (Chequear que esté instalado)
php --ini (Buscar la ruta, en mi caso: /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini)
nano /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini (agregué las extensiones necesarias)

apt update
apt install php8.1-curl 
apt install php8.1-mbstring 
apt install php8.1-mysql 
apt install php8.1-soap
apt install php8.1-mailparse
apt install python3
apt install python3-pip
apt install unzip
apt install curl
apt update
apt upgrade
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
composer update --no-interaction --no-ansi --ignore-platform-reqs

mkdir -p /repo/api
chmod -R 777 /repo/api

git clone {url del proyecto laravel}
./vendor/bin/sail up -d

php artisan migrate
```

(acá empieza lo divertido)

Me devuelve: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory**

Voy al .env y cambió de DB_HOST=localhost a DB_HOST=127.0.0.1

Vuelvo a correr 'php artisan migrate' y ahí me devuelve: **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused**

Probé de todo, lo de stackoverflow que encontré en eng y esp, chat gpt.... Esto alguna vez me pasó y lo habá resuelto borrando el archivo **mysql.sock.lock** que se encuentra en \wsl.localhost\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes\api_sail-mysql_data pero ahora lo borro y cuando reinicio el contenedor se vuelve a crear. Probé con apuntar el proyecto al server de windows y tampoco me deja.

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3308 (en el 3308 tengo la que está en docker y en el 3306 la que está en windows)
DB_DATABASE=api
DB_USERNAME=sail
DB_PASSWORD=
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3308}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

Datos adicionales:

-A ambas db puedo acceder con workbench tanto con el user root como con sail

-Si en el .env coloco los datos de una db hosteada en aws me conecta sin ningún problema.

Comment: Cada vez que hagas cambios en el .env tienes que usar `php artisan optimize` o `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de la siguiente forma:

**-Entré a la base de datos local desde workbench**

**-Fui a 'Administration'->'Client Connections'**

**-Busqué la ip que fuigura en 'Host' y la coloqué en el .env en DB_HOST**

Funciona, aunque es un solución temporal. Tengo que ver porqué no asignó DB como 'api' (es lo que debería según el .env y el .yml) y en cambio asignó 'mysql'; y como usuario no creó a 'sail'.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.